# Mathemetic series 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45,__?

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

I currently looking what will be the next value to 45 as per given series.

Is there any specific equation available?

Comment: Look at the differences between adjacent numbers. Perhaps you can see a pattern.

Comment: So it means my answer will be 55? Correct?

Comment: You might want to investigate triangular numbers in your spare time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply the sum of the first n numbers:

$$t_n = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}i = \frac{n\cdot(n+1)}2$$

Comment: And so the next number is 45 + 10 = 55.

Comment: @MikeQ Yes of course. We can also simply state $t_n = t_{n-1} + n$ with $t_1 = 1$

Comment: Thank you so much @PaulEvans, This is what I looking for.